# Cocos2d-x drag finger and sprite follows at a steady pace

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am trying get an effect like a flight control game. the user drags their finger on the screen, it stores that data in an array, then the item follows that path to where the finger was lifted.

I have the code for this working, my problem is that i want it to be at a steady pace like in the games, when my sprite moves it varies in speed by how fast you move your finger.

any help would be appreciated.

im fairly certain it has to do with my CCMoveTo action, but i cant really think of any other way to do this.

```
void WavePrototypeInterface::ccTouchesBegan(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)
{
        while (movementPath->count() != 0)
        {
        movementPath->removeControlPointAtIndex(0);
        }
     index=0;
    this->stopAllActions();
 }  

void WavePrototypeInterface::ccTouchesMoved(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)
{
      CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch*)( touches->anyObject() );
    CCPoint location = touch->getLocationInView();
    location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);

    movementPath->addControlPoint(location);

    int xValue = movementPath->count();

}

void WavePrototypeInterface::ccTouchesEnded(CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event)
{
if(!movementPath->count()<=0)
    {
        goToPointWithIndex();

    }
}

void WavePrototypeInterface::goToPointWithIndex()
{
  CCPoint toPoint = movementPath->getControlPointAtIndex(index);

   if(index <  movementPath->count())
   {
       index++;
       sprite->setPosition(toPoint);

       CCDelayTime * delay = CCDelayTime::create(0.1);
       CCCallFunc *func = CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(WavePrototypeInterface::goToPointWithIndex));
       CCSequence * seq = CCSequence::createWithTwoActions(delay, func);
       this->runAction(seq);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may record each point into an array as a path. And execute the path in the update loop.
In this case, I dont recommend you to use CCMoveTo or other actions. You should update the position of your item manually.
Calcuate a move step every frame and apply it to your item.

*** EXAMPLE CODE ***

```
//example code
void update(delta){
float step = delta*MOVESPEED;
while(step>0){
    CGPoint target = getNextPointInPath();
    float distance = ccpDistance(target, item.position);
    if( distance > step ){
        CGPoint dir = ccpSub(target, item.position);
        dir = ccpNormalize(dir);
        CGPoint newpoint = ccpAdd(item.position, ccpMult(dir, step));
        item.position = newpoint;
        step = 0;
    }else{
        item.positon = target;
        step -= distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have thought of that also, im just not sure exactly what would be in the update loop. can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

**ccTouchesMoved**  is invoked in a certain frequency .

which means if you move your finger slower , you'll get more points , if you move your finger faster , you'll get less points.

and in the function  **goToPointWithIndex()**  ， you set the delay between each point 1 sec , so you get the result .

you should take the **distance** between each point into consideration.